# Assigning function pointer within a class gives value type error in C++

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I've got this code within Entity.h, which is inherited by other classes. The idea is that in the inheriting classes can change the function either to avoid inheritance or to modify behavior.

```
public:
Entity(void)
{
    updateFunction = emptyFunction;
};
~Entity(void);
protected:
    void emptyFunction(){}
void (*updateFunction)();
```

The problem is that I get this error on compilation:

```
Error   2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl Entity::* )(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'    c:\documents and settings\administrator\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\projectname\[projectname]\Entity.h 16  1   [projectname]
```

I've looked at tutorials all over again, it's been a while since I learned these stuff, but I cannot see some dissimilarity, what could be going wrong? IntelliSense unrelines the '=' symbol as the point of the mistake. I hope I didn't overlook anything.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Normally, you would just have a virtual member function: `virtual void updateFunction() {}`. Derived classes can override it as they see fit.

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is that `updateFunction` is a pointer to a regular, non-member function, while `emptyFunction` is, of course, a non-static member function. These two types are not interchangeable, since member functions can't be called on their own - they need an object instance to be called on.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, at first I tried that but I got a runtime error, the program counter (I presume) was pointing at an invalid area when trying to override, but then I realized that I could also use function pointers to change behavior later on, solving two problems at once. Of course I know that I will have to make overriding work too, but I can afford to postpone that one for now. The answer solved this problem, but I got another one (see comment on answer). I did not see anything about instances required, but I'll keep it in mind if I get something similar in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decalre pointer function as:

```
class Entity{
public:
    Entity(void)
    {
        updateFunction = &Entity::emptyFunction;
        // ...
        (this->*updateFunction)(); //Call
    };
    ~Entity(void);
protected:
    void emptyFunction(){}
    void (Entity::*updateFunction)();
};
```

In fact `updateFunction` is not a normal function and it's a class member function.

Comment: I can see the next question coming up, how to make call(back)s upon that thang actually :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, I got an error calling it, you pretty much guessed it :P The error reads: "Error 1 error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments", and InteliSense says "Expression must have (pointer-to-) function type", so yeah, how do I call it? I tried derefferencer but that's obliously not the answer...

Comment: @user3079666 I've been searching the site using the query [**\[c++\] member function pointers what is**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5Dmember+function+pointers+what+is) and could find many many Q&A's that will give you a clue about the problem. But unfortunately I wasn't able to find one that's really appropriate to mark your question as a duplicate. You shouldn't accept answers too quickly, unless they're giving you a full and satisfying solution. May be you also need to improve your question to clarify about your problems.

Comment: I read through quite a few tutorials and tried to duplicate what they were doing, I did not find something that used function pointers within classes, that's why I decided to ask here.Now, the exact problem I stated in the question was answered with success - the error left, and from there on it is my own lack of knowledge that is responsible for the question that came after it, and not a lack on behalf of the answer (strictly speaking that is, because it would be nice if it also answered the question that was logically coming up next)

Comment: Ok, I withdraw my last question, the asnwer above is right, my mistake was not copying the entirety (or rather all modified parts) of the question. The function must be called as above to work directly.